# Font size changes itself after pasting, Summernote

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

I'm using the summernote library. I noticed that when copying and pasting text (maybe not only then), the font size changes by itself. Everything looks fine in the textarea, but the text is still 1pt. Is this a Summernote error? Has anyone had a similar problem and solved it? I am throwing screenshots below.

[image: Select text and CTRL+C]

[image: This is 16pt]

[image: Pasted text is 1pt]